# php print filecontent with php-content

Tags: php, get, fopen, fread

After checking for both fread and fopen with the search-command "php fread php code" and php fopen php code" without success I'm now turning to asking the question myself. (Over 300 pages with questions were a bit to steep to dig around in.)

I have a page where I get the content from external files. I got the index.php with the links which sends requests through the url (?links=home, for example) that is read from another file that looks through an array and finds the right file. All that works! But here is the tricky part:
On of the files includes a few strings of php-codes that won't do it's job but just hangs around in the view-source. Yes, you can see the commands in the source:code, but it won't anything I request. Not a single echo.

Here is some code that might explain things even better.

The code that gets the url-command:

```
<?php
function load_pages() {
    if ($_GET['link'] != NULL) {
        $link = $_GET['link'];
        $links = array("hem" => "hem.php", "about" => "about.php", "blogg" => "blogg.php", "kontakta" => "kontakta.php");
        foreach ($links as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == $link) {
                $file = "links/" . $value;
                $fh = fopen($file, "r") or exit("Unable to open the file.");
                $fileContent = fread($fh, filesize($file));
                fclose($fh);
                echo $fileContent;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $file = "links/hem.php";
        $fh = fopen($file, "r") or exit("Unable to open the file.");
        $fileContent = fread($fh, filesize($file));
        fclose($fh);
        echo $fileContent;
    }
}
?>
```

The file that gets the command for the page I want to load:

```
<?php
include ("../include/functions.php");
connect();
?>

<h1>Blogg</h1>
<?php
if ($_GET['id'] == NULL) {
    blogg_content();
} else {
    blogg_link();
}
?>

<div id="blogg_menu">
    <?php blogg_menu(); ?>
</div>
```

What comes out is: Blogg
That just doesn't do the trick, so what might I change to make it give me the blog-content and such? (The page is on Swedish, just to disclaim any typos about "Blogg".)

Comment: Aren't you just looking for the `include` statement, possibly with an `ob_start` in front of it? (Oh, and always `require_once` or `include_once` function files).

Comment: It won't read any php, so include would be useless in this case. I had an include-tag before, got it in the index-page as well.

Comment: Euhm, if `include` is not what you're after, I am utterly confused about what you want to sent to the client. Raw PHP code? Because that is what you have now, and it seems to be not what you want.

Comment: I got the include on the index-file and I had it on the the blog-file as well. But it didn't work out at all. If you got an idea, could you please post an example-code for me?

Comment: A short snippet from the view-source:
<div id="content"> 
<?php include ("../include/functions.php"); connect(); ?> | This is not from my editor, but view-source in the web-browser.

Comment: Yes, because you send the _raw_ PHP code (it should be handled on the server if you don't want that). Do this 2 things: (1) Every `include` of your `functions.php` file should become a `include_once` in all files from the `$links` array. (2) Then `include` those files instead of reading them. If that doesn't work, please describe for us what actually happens if you say 'didn't work out at all'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those files contain PHP code that you want to be executed you need to `include` or `require` them rather than echoing the raw data.

Please see [PHP's documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) on how to include code files.

**EDIT**
Kind of hard to tell from your description but if at all, you would have to do something like:

```
...
if ($key == $link) {
    $file = "links/" . $value;
    include_once $file;
}
...
```

Comment: Include demands a php-tag, and it doesn't allow me use php-scripts with my code. You would only see the include in view-source, but won't make any other differences to the site.

Comment: Of course not, you are reading in raw text data and pushing that to the client. You either have to find a way to include these files or do a nasty parse and eval to mimic PHP's include mechanism (you really don't want to get started with this kind of thing, trust me).

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how I could do? I got an include-file on the index-page, and I can read for all documents without any problem. But this script can't do php-code work for me.